# Finding largest family in graph

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, family-tree

This is a homework for a data structures course. I'm not asking for code, but I have hard time coming up with an effective algorithm for this :l

I have information about different family trees. Among those I have to find out the largest family and return the name of the greatest elder and number of his descendants. The descendants may have kids between them (a brother and a sister may have a kid) and this has to be done in at least O(n^2).

What would be the most effective way to solve this? I imagine having a breadth first search on graphs, but that means I have to keep up children counters for many levels upwards (if I am traversing a grand^99 children for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMIIW, but my assumption is every family tree is separated from each other and the root is the eldest ancestor. If that's the case, since you're counting all tree nodes regardless, I think any unweighted graph traversal algorithm would give the same result. BFS would do the job. I don't get what you mean by "keeping up children counters for many levels upwards" though, just 1 counter is fine right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I guess I brainfarted on those level counters, BFS will be just fine. Thanks :)